# Python - Storing the average of from files in loop; and then finding global average outside of loop?

Tags: python, pandas, average, glob

I have a function below which currently loops through the files starting with "K" and "Z", and plots the "Temp" data; blue for "K" data and red for "Z" data.  This works very nicely for my goal.

**Where I'm stuck:**

1. I want to now take the average of the "Temp" between sample 100 and sample 350 for each file in the loop.
2. Then, I want to store each file's average in a new dataFrame with a column for the "K" averages and a column for the "Z" averages.
3. Finally, outside of the loop, I want to take the average of the "K" column and the average of the "Z" column; and plot it on the chart.

In my code below, I've placed comments in the areas where I am stuck.

As a side question, if someone knows of a good method to automatically detect the "flat" area of each dataset (slope ~= 0) and then automatically select the interval to average over; that would be an additional cool thing to have!  Because right now, for sure, I'm going to lose some data points by setting a fixed interval.

```
filenamesK = glob("C:/Users/K*.csv")
filenamesZ = glob("C:/Users/Z*.csv")

def plot_data(filename, fig_ax, color):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',',skiprows=24)
    df.columns=['sample','Temp']
    df=df.astype(str)

    df["Temp"] = df["Temp"].str.replace('\+ ', '').str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)
    
    # Now take the average of df["Temp"] from sample 100 until sample 350.
    
    # Append this average to a K_Z_Averages, containing a column for average 
    # from each K file and the average from each Z file.
    
    fig_ax.plot(df[["Temp"]], color=color)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for f in filenamesK:
    plot_data(f, ax, 'blue')

for f in filenamesZ:
    plot_data(f, ax, 'red')

# After the loop is finished, take the average of each column in K_Z_averages 
# with each average from the K files and from the Z files.    
    
plt.show()
```

**Part 2:**
If my .csv files have a second Temp, "Temp2", which I want to extract, can you support to add it into the `dict` ?  For example, having a column in the `dict` for *K_Temp, K_Temp2, Z_Temp, Z_Temp2* ?

I modified my code with what I think might work, but I imagine there is a more efficient method to do this:

```
filenamesK = glob("C:/Users/K*.csv")
filenamesZ = glob("C:/Users/Z*.csv")

# Create dict of lists for storing the averages
K_Z_Averages = {'K':[], 'Z':[]}

def plot_data(filename, fig_ax, color):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',',skiprows=24)
    df.columns=['sample','Temp','Temp2']
    df=df.astype(str)

    df["Temp"] = df["Temp"].str.replace('\+ ', '').str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)
    df["Temp2"] = df["Temp2"].str.replace('\+ ', '').str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)
    
    # Now take the average of df["Temp"] from sample 100 until sample 350.
    avg_Temp1 = df.iloc[100-1:350+1]['Temp'].mean()
    avg_Temp2 = df.iloc[100-1:350+1]['Temp2'].mean()
    
    # Append this average to a K_Z_Averages, containing a column for average 
    # from each K file and the average from each Z file.
    K_Z_Averages[filename.split('/')[-1][0]].append(avg_Temp1)
    K_Z_Averages[filename.split('/')[-1][0]].append(avg_Temp2)
    
    fig_ax.plot(df[["Temp"]], color=color)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for f in filenamesK:
    plot_data(f, ax, 'blue')

for f in filenamesZ:
    plot_data(f, ax, 'red')

# Take the overall average 
df_avg = pd.DataFrame(K_Z_Averages).mean() 

# Add vertical lines for each mean
ax.vlines(df_avg, *ax.get_ylim(), linestyles='--', colors=['blue','red'], alpha=.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary for storing the averages per file, then use it to append the averages:

```py
# Before the the `plot_data` definition
K_Z_Averages = {'K':[], 'Z':[]}

# Inside the function
avg = df.iloc[100-1:350+1]['Temp'].mean()
K_Z_Averages[filename.split('/')[-1][0]].append(avg)
```

where `filename.split('/')[-1][0]` remove the path extension and takes the first letter of the filename (which is similar to using `os.path.basename(filename)[0]`).

Then, to take the overall average of the averages:

```py
pd.DataFrame(K_Z_Averages).mean()
```

---

The full code should look like:

```py
filenamesK = glob("C:/Users/K*.csv")
filenamesZ = glob("C:/Users/Z*.csv")

# Create dict of lists for storing the averages
K_Z_Averages = {'K':[], 'Z':[]}

def plot_data(filename, fig_ax, color):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',',skiprows=24)
    df.columns=['sample','Temp']
    df=df.astype(str)

    df["Temp"] = df["Temp"].str.replace('\+ ', '').str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)
    
    # Now take the average of df["Temp"] from sample 100 until sample 350.
    avg = df.iloc[100-1:350+1]['Temp'].mean()
    
    # Append this average to a K_Z_Averages, containing a column for average 
    # from each K file and the average from each Z file.
    K_Z_Averages[filename.split('/')[-1][0]].append(avg)
    
    fig_ax.plot(df[["Temp"]], color=color)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for f in filenamesK:
    plot_data(f, ax, 'blue')

for f in filenamesZ:
    plot_data(f, ax, 'red')

# Take the overall average 
df_avg = pd.DataFrame(K_Z_Averages).mean() 

# Add vertical lines for each mean
ax.vlines(df_avg, *ax.get_ylim(), linestyles='--', colors=['blue','red'], alpha=.5)

plt.show()
```

---

After question edition (Part 2), the code should look like:

```py
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
from os.path import basename
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filenamesK = glob("C:/Users/K*.csv")
filenamesZ = glob("C:/Users/Z*.csv")

# Create dict of lists for storing the averages
K_Z_Averages = {'K_Temp':[], 'K_Temp2': [], 'Z_Temp':[], 'Z_Temp2': []}

def plot_data(filename, fig_ax, color):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',',skiprows=24)
    df.columns=['sample','Temp','Temp2']
    df=df.astype(str)

    df["Temp"] = df["Temp"].str.replace('\+ ', '').str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)
    df["Temp2"] = df["Temp2"].str.replace('\+ ', '').str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)
    
    # Now take the average of df["Temp"] from sample 100 until sample 350.
    avg_Temp1 = df.iloc[100-1:350+1]['Temp'].mean()
    avg_Temp2 = df.iloc[100-1:350+1]['Temp2'].mean()
    
    # Append this average to a K_Z_Averages, containing a column for average 
    # from each K file and the average from each Z file.
    K_Z_Averages[basename(filename)[0] + "_Temp"].append(avg_Temp1)
    K_Z_Averages[basename(filename)[0] + "_Temp2"].append(avg_Temp2)
    
    fig_ax.plot(df[["Temp"]], color=color)
    fig_ax.plot(df[["Temp2"]], color=color)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for f in filenamesK:
    plot_data(f, ax, 'blue')
    plot_data(f, ax, 'darkblue')

for f in filenamesZ:
    plot_data(f, ax, 'red')
    plot_data(f, ax, 'darkred')

# Take the overall average 
df_avg = pd.DataFrame(K_Z_Averages).mean() 

# Add vertical lines for each mean
ax.vlines(df_avg, *ax.get_ylim(), linestyles='--', colors=['blue','darkblue','red','darkred'], alpha=.5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the support!  One issue I'm seeing.  I'm getting a 'KeyError: 'C' ', at the line, "K_Z_Averages[filename[0]].append(avg)".  Do you know some troubleshooting I can do to resolve this?

Comment: @Gary that's true! I forgot the `glob` returns the whole path. You can replace `0` for `10` (see update), or take use `filename.split('/')[-1][0]`, or even `os.path.basename(filename)[0]`.

Comment: Wow, works great.  Cheers bud!  Thanks for your support!  I used `os.path.basename(filename)[0]`

Comment: I added a Part 2 to my original question, if you may be able to support?  Basically, I want to now adapt my code to incorporate one more column of data from my csv.

Comment: Hi @Gary, I've add the code for part 2, hope it works! Note the lines of `dict` creation, `append`. Also, note that I added "Temp2" lines/avg to the plot, but since I don't have the data for testing, I can only guess it works. Best!

Comment: Also, since you're already using four keys in the dictionary, it's worth it taking a look at [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) using list as default item.

Comment: Worked great!  Thanks again, it's hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood the second portion of the 'K_Z_Average' question. But here goes:

```
    # Now take the average of df["Temp"] from sample 100 until sample 350.
    average_temperature=df.iloc[100:350]['Temp'].mean()
   
    # Append this average to a K_Z_Averages, containing a column for average 
    # from each K file and the average from each Z file.
    df['K_Z_Average']=average_temparature
```

Comment: Note that here you're taking the mean of samples (*i.e.* rows) from 101 (since it starts with 0) to 349 (since it's not inclusive at the end). Also, we gonna need to store these values somewhere to retrieve them later on (this `df` is only temporary).

Comment: Got it -  your answer seems to be complete.